# JCIFS : Does anyone know the full list of dependent JARs to run jcifs-ng (or drop logging altogether)?

Tags: java, networking, smb, jcifs

Going in circles for a few days now, chiefly because of dependent upon **Clf4j** and **Apache** loggers referring to each other, and hissing on version/method/class incompatibility. Tons of links on Google are obsolete too.

Wonder - for those of us who have been able to use the **jcifs-ng** library - if you have a list of jars for the classpath that all agree with each other?

Or, better yet, if there is an env variable to ditch the logging altogether.

Trying to push a file from Unix to Windows, with no direct access to the Win server, and it looks like the Smb1 is not supported there either.

Comment: Are you using maven? Because I would use [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/eu.agno3.jcifs/jcifs-ng/2.1.9).

Comment: just direct compilation from Unix via make

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and check [ask]